# "Nested foreach" vs "lambda/linq query" performance(LINQ-to-Objects)

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach, linq-to-objects

In performance point of view what should you use "Nested foreach's" or "lambda/linq queries"?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hazzik/6912865 tl;dr nested `foreach` is faster than `SelectMany`, but `foreach` + `List.AddRange()` is fastest

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Write the clearest code you can, and then benchmark and profile to discover any performance problems. If you *do* have performance problems, you can experiment with different code to work out whether it's faster or not (measuring all the time with as realistic data as possible) and then make a judgement call as to whether the improvement in performance is worth the readability hit.

A direct `foreach` approach *will* be faster than LINQ in many cases. For example, consider:

```
var query = from element in list
            where element.X > 2
            where element.Y < 2
            select element.X + element.Y;

foreach (var value in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Now there are two `where` clauses and a `select` clause, so every eventual item has to pass through three iterators. (Obviously the two where clauses could be combined in this case, but I'm making a general point.)

Now compare it with the direct code:

```
foreach (var element in list)
{
    if (element.X > 2 && element.Y < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.X + element.Y);
    }
}
```

That will run faster, because it has fewer hoops to run through. Chances are that the console output will dwarf the iterator cost though, and I'd certainly prefer the LINQ query.

EDIT: To answer about "nested foreach" loops... typically those are represented with `SelectMany` or a second `from` clause:

```
var query = from item in firstSequence
            from nestedItem in item.NestedItems
            select item.BaseCount + nestedItem.NestedCount;
```

Here we're only adding a single extra iterator, because we'd already be using an extra iterator per item in the first sequence due to the nested `foreach` loop. There's still a bit of overhead, including the overhead of doing the projection in a delegate instead of "inline" (something I didn't mention before) but it still won't be very different to the nested-foreach performance.

This is not to say you can't shoot yourself in the foot with LINQ, of course. You can write stupendously inefficient queries if you don't engage your brain first - but that's far from unique to LINQ...

Comment: The first sentence should be printed out as a banner and hung in every programming department.

Answer (score 26):

If you do

```
foreach(Customer c in Customer)
{
  foreach(Order o in Orders)
  {
    //do something with c and o
  }
}
```

You will perform Customer.Count * Order.Count iterations

---

If you do

```
var query =
  from c in Customer
  join o in Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
  select new {c, o}

foreach(var x in query)
{
  //do something with x.c and x.o
}
```

You will perform Customer.Count + Order.Count iterations, because Enumerable.Join is implemented as a HashJoin.

Comment: great answer with a good explanation

Comment: That's because you're running two different algorithms; you're comparing apples to oranges.  I don't see how this is relevant to the question posed.

Comment: Your nested foreach is actually equivalent to SelectMany, not Join - i.e. from c in Customer from o in Orders ... (no join)

Comment: Upvote! @mquander: It's not very unlikely that the OP will have "if (c.CustomerID != o.CustomerID) continue;" as the first statement inside the loop.

Comment: Nice explanation. How can I modify the query for a left outer join? I have 2 nested loops, but the common field could be null. In that case I insert else update.

Comment: Got it Sir, worked it out myself after some trial and error. I was learning LINQ and adapting it for day to day tasks. Your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 13):

It is more complex on that. Ultimately, much of LINQ-to-Objects is (behind the scenes) a `foreach` loop, but with the added overhead of a little abstraction / iterator blocks / etc. However, unless you do very different things in your two versions (foreach vs LINQ), they should both be O(N).

The real question is: is there a better way of writing your **specific** algorithm that means that `foreach` would be inefficient? And can LINQ do it for you?

For example, LINQ makes it easy to hash / group / sort data.

Comment: May I ask what is O(N)?

Comment: @Jeb50 that's a common way of indicating the performance characteristics of something; O(N) means that the time taken scales linearly as a factor of the number of elements (N). O(N) is almost always fine - naive sorting would be O(N^2), for example, which is much worse, but exponential (for example O(2^N)) or super-exponential (for example O(N!)) would be worse again.

Answer (score 3):

It's been said before, but it merits repeating.

Developers never know where the performance bottleneck is until they run performance tests.

The same is true for comparing technique A to technique B. Unless there is a dramatic difference then you just have to test it. It might be obvious if you have an O(n) vs O(n^x) scenario, but since the LINQ stuff is mostly compiler witchcraft, it merits a profiling.

Besides, unless your project is in production and you have profiled the code and found that that loop is slowing down your execution, leave it as whichever is your preference for readability and maintenance. Premature optimization is the devil.

Comment: While it is true that you cannot truly anticipate performance bottlenecks, it is also true that most performance issues are designed in, are found very late in the development life cycle and are therefore difficult to code out.  There is a great deal to be said for always having an eye open to the performance implications of the design and implementation decisions you are making, rather than blithely coding away hoping it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

A great benefit is that using Linq-To-Objects queries gives you the ability to easily turn the query over to PLinq and have the system automatically perform he operation on the correct number of threads for the current system.

If you are using this technique on big datasets, that's an easily become a big win for very little trouble.

Comment: True but there are also parallel equivalents proposed for foreach as well.

http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2009/01/parallelising-loops-in-net-4.html