# If statement or Where extension with a For Each loop?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, linq-to-objects

I was wondering which of the two code samples would be more efficient (or is the difference between the two negligible)?

```
For Each apple in AppleController.GetRedApples().Where(Function(a) PriceController.OnSale(a))
   'do something
Next
```

or

```
For Each apple in AppleController.GetRedApples()
   If PriceController.OnSale(apple) Then
      'do something
   End If
Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is negligible, and the second code is much more readable, so you should probably prefer that one

Comment: Interesting point on readability, I've always wondered why VB.NET never improved there. With the event of LINQ, the readability gap between C# and VB only became larger, which has become a huge liability for VB coders.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally separate it out:

```
Dim applesOnSale = AppleController.GetRedApples() _
                                  .Where(Function(a) PriceController.OnSale(a))
For Each apple in applesOnSale
   'do something
Next
```

In a full IDE the first part could be a single line - or you could use a VB query expression like this:

```
Dim applesOnSale = From apple in AppleController.GetRedApples() _
                   Where PriceController.OnSale(apple)

For Each apple in applesOnSale
   'do something
Next
```

This separates the "what items you're interested in" from "what you want to do with the items" which I personally find useful in terms of readability.

Note that in some situations the `Where` may not work, however - if `GetRedApples` returns a table from a LINQ to SQL `DataContext`, for example, it will try to translate the `Where` clause into SQL - which won't work.

Assuming you're using LINQ to Objects though, the assignment won't actually do any looping - it will just set up the query. The "where" clause will only be evaluated for each item as you loop through the query.

Comment: +1: Separating 'what's interesting' and 'what am I going to do with it' was going to be my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this discussion on [foreach vs linq/lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044236/nested-foreach-vs-lambda-linq-query-performancelinq-to-objects) (also answer by Jon Skeet ;-) and this one if you want to [delve deeper into understanding LINQ / Lambda efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182922/what-is-the-efficiency-and-performance-of-linq-and-lambda-expression-in-net) and performance.

Answer (score 0):

The performance should be about the same, therefore I would go for the more readable approach:

```
var applesOnSale = from apple in AppleController.GetRedApples()
                   where PriceController.OnSale(apple)
                   select apple;

foreach(var apple in applesOnSale)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This is the same as your second option but is a touch more readable.

Comment: Just realized that the original question was in VB.NET, I don't want to attempt to port this to vb.net (since I am not that well versed in it's syntax) but I am sure the same can be done.

Comment: I wouldn't actually use a query expression in this case - given that you're forced to use "select" it ends up being "fluffier" than just calling Where directly. However, queries in VB don't require a select clause, so in VB a query expression is probably better.