# How can I switch that code to use LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know that is [good practice](http://www.linqtutorial.net/linqexamples.html) use LINQ instead of iterative loops, can I modify this code to use LINQ?

```
List<string> priorsLstIDs = ServiceUtil.extractColumnValuesAsStringVals(tqrPriors,Helper.STUDY_ID);
List<DateTime> priorsLstDates = ServiceUtil.extractColumnValuesAsDateTimeVals(tqrPriors, "STUDY_DATE");
List<PriorElemSt> priorsElemLst = new List<PriorElemSt>(priorsLstIDs.Count);

PriorElemSt elem;

for (int i = 0; i < priorsLstIDs.Count; i++)
{
    elem = new PriorElemSt(priorsLstIDs[i], priorsLstDates[i]);
    priorsElemLst.Add(elem);
}

return filterStudyPriors(priorsElemLst);
```

Thanks.

**Update:** can the call to `filterStudyPriors()` method can be part of the LINQ?

Comment: Don't switch just because you read it's good practice. In tight loops, for example, iterative code can be much faster.

Comment: I would add.  I some cases iterative loops are much simpler for others to modify. Don't make everything a nail just because you have a hammer.

Comment: @Delashmate: What is the body of this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<PriorElemSt> priorsElemLst = priorsLstIDs.Select((s,i) => new PriorElemSt(s, priorsLstDates[i]));
return filterStudyPriors(priorsElemLst);
```

Comment: The signature is IEnumerable<PriorElemSt>

Comment: @Delashmate: Then the second part of my answer is more suitable for you.

Comment: This won't compile, in your answer `i` will be a string but needs to be an integer to pass to the list as an index.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Now it will. Thanks.

Comment: You can make it shorter, since `s` already is `priorsLstIDs[i]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method

```
var priorsElemLst = priorsLstIDs.Zip(
    priorsLstDates, (i, d) => new PriorElemSt(i, d))
```

In the above statement `i` is the item from priorsLstIds and `d` the item from priorsLstDates. They will be 'zipped' together using their positions in their lists.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method like so:

```
//first get the range of indexes
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, priorsLstIDs.Count);
//now project a list of elements at each index
var priorsElemLst = range.Select(i => new PriorElemSt(priorsLstIDs[i], priorsLstDates[i])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

it is not a best practice at all but only if you think it will improve the readability against a performance loss.

*LINQ-to-Objects generally is going to add some marginal overheads (multiple iterators, etc). It still has to do the loops, and has delegate invokes, and will generally have to do some extra dereferencing to get at captured variables etc.*

[Is a LINQ statement faster than a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/linq-statement-faster-than-foreach-loop)