# Convert foreach loop with repeater in linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, foreach

How can I convert below code in LINQ

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptNews.Items)
            {
                HiddenField hdnUserId = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnId");
                int userId = Users.Current.UserId;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(hdnUserId.Value) != userId)
                {
                    ((ImageButton)ri.FindControl("img1")).Visible = false;
                    ((ImageButton)ri.FindControl("img2")).Visible = false;

                }

            }
```

Also please guide me how can I learn to translate this kind of code to linq.

Comment: Why do you want to "translate" this code into LINQ? It looks fine as it is. LINQ is not the solution to every problem.

Comment: I read that Linq is faster and I have so many items in repeater. So I thought LINQ can work better than traditional foreach loop. I am not sure because I am new to linq :-(

Comment: Whether or not LINQ is faster is irrelevant if what you have now is readable and fast enough.

Comment: Given that LINQ is not intended for causing side-effects, you really should loop somewhere.

Comment: I am confused now because of my limited knowledge in LINQ. Does that mean that foreach is best in this case ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite LINQ is NOT faster than foreach or for loops. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/linq-statement-faster-than-foreach-loop

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite, `foreach` gets the job done. You could refactor it into a LINQ query, apply `ToList()` to it and pass a lambda to the `ForEach()` method of the resulting list, but the end result will probably perform the same and only be less readable.

Comment: LINQ may hide the loop a little bit but would certainly not eliminate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq is intended to select a subset of data not just iterate over a collection. In your example you are not selecting anything, you are simply looping through a collection. Linq is not the correct tool for what you are trying to achieve.

Regarding your comment that Linq is *faster*, a linq query will eventually boil down to a series of `for` and `if` statements once the compiler has worked its magic, so I doubt it would be any faster than you `foreach` even if you could use it without a `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I found the  [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746/)  guide on MSDN very useful when learning LINQ.

Have a look at the examples and have a go at re-writing the above query yourself - it's the only way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for it, find it below:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in from RepeaterItem ri in rptNews.Items let hdnUserId = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnId") let userId = Users.Current.UserId where Convert.ToInt32(hdnUserId.Value) != userId select ri)
            {
                ((ImageButton)ri.FindControl("img1")).Visible = false; 
                ((ImageButton)ri.FindControl("img2")).Visible = false;
            }
```