# LastIndexOf in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using LINQ to Entities to fetch elements from a MSSQL data base and I need them sorted by the last index of a string:

```
var data = db.GetEntities().
           OrderBy(e=>e.StringProperty.LastIndexOf("Foo")).ToList()
```

However, LINQ to Entities does not support `LastIndexOf`. I've tried searching for similar questions but all I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261991/get-last-index-of-character-with-linq-to-entities) which does not address my issue (ordering). Searching on MSDN did not yield any results.

What would be the simplest way to accomplish this using LINQ to Entities (I don't want to have to do this after the `ToList())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
OrderBy(e => e.StringProperty.Length - EntityFunctions.Reverse(e.StringProperty).IndexOf("ooF"))
```

I think `Reverse` and `IndexOf` are supported.

Comment: I think you would need to use [EntityFunctions.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @James Thanks, regular `Reverse` gives you an `IEnumerable<char>` which isn't much use :)

Comment: If the string is not found, the result would by the length, not zero. But otherwise great solution.

Comment: I mean -1, not zero if the string is not found.

Comment: @MarcelDevG You're right, although I'm sure it's not too hard to work around :)

Comment: In EF6, `EntityFunctions` has been replaced by [`DbFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Do the sorting using LINQ to Objects

```
var data = db.GetEntities()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(e => e.StringProperty.LastIndexOf("Foo"))
    .ToList();
```

Using `AsEnumerable` will allow you to retain deferred execution, it's the better compromise than calling `ToList` and *then* performing the `OrderBy`.

Comment: That misses the point completely - OP specifically asked `I don't want to have to do this after the ToList()` meaning he doesn't want to enumerate the entities. This misses the point of EF

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think you maybe misunderstand how `AsEnumerable` works, it doesn't enumerate the entities, the query is still only evaluated when `ToList` is called...

Comment: But the sorting would be on the client, not on the server

Comment: @MarcelDevG yes it would, however, it's not always such a bad idea, EF is restricted by the DB so sometimes complicated queries can't be done server-side. If it's not a massive amount of data I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: @James, True, if it is only sorting, and in some cases it's even preferable. But if you combine with a where clause, I would not do it this way.

Comment: @MarcelDevG you would simply do the `Where` before you call `AsEnumerable` though.