# How to get the last sub string from the url using linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this linq query

```
List<Details> DetailList = new List<Details>();

DetailList = (from areadetails in context.AreaDetails.Where(x => (bool)x.IsActive && x.Area == area) 
                                  join jobdetails in context.JobDetails.Where(x => x.IsActive) on jobdetails.BuildDetailID equals areadetails.BuildDetailID
                                  select new Details
                                  {
                                      Area = areadetails.AreaName,
                                      JobLink = (jobdetails.EJ2JobLink != null) ? jobdetails.JobLink + "/console" : null,
                                      JobId = (jobdetails.EJ2JobLink != null) ? jobdetails.JobLink.Split('/').Last() : null
                                  }).ToList();
```

**JobLink = job/it/development/41**

I have to get the **job id(41)** from the link. When I have run this(**JobLink.Split('/').Last()**) separately in console application get correct job id from the link.When I used in linq.

**I got an exception like this:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

Anyone know why? Anyone know an alternative way of doing this to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri)

Answer (score 0):

Either use the approach mentioned in the answer that @Stephen Kennedy linked in the comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri) or split the string by some way that can be mapped to a database query - this should work:

```
 JobId = (jobdetails.EJ2JobLink != null) ? jobdetails.JobLink.Substring(jobDetails.JobLink.Length - EntityFunctions.Reverse(e.jobDetails.JobLink).IndexOf('/') + 1) : null
```

/Edit: Updated as LastIndexOf [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140550/3085985).