# Entity Framework Core mapping columns to object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a string that represents a query. The query is quite complex and it involves multiple joins. Here's what I'm selecting:

```sql
SELECT 
    [SO].Id, [SO].SerialNumber, [SO].EstimateId,
    CASE
        WHEN [SO].EstimateId IS NOT NULL 
            THEN (SELECT TOP(1) [EST].[SerialNumber]
                  FROM [Estimates] AS [EST]
                  WHERE ([EST].[OrganizationId] = 1) 
                    AND ([EST].[EstimateId] = [SO].[EstimateId]))
            ELSE NULL
    END, 
    [SO].RecCreateTs, [SO].EstimatedDeliveryDate, [SO].Status, 
    [SO].PriceTotal, [SO].InRevision, [CST].CompanyName, 
    [CON].FirstName, [CON].LastName, [SOR].FirstName, [SOR].LastName, 
    [SOR].EstimatedDeliveryDate, [SOR].PriceTotal
```

Some columns are identical, but they come from different tables.

I tried to map the properties inside the Select:

```cs
var salesOrders = _context.SalesOrders.FromSqlRaw(sqlString)
    .Select(so => new SalesOrder
    {
        Id = so.Id,
        SerialNumber = so.SerialNumber,
        EstimateId = so.EstimateId,
        // the property below is [NotMapped]
        EstimateSerialNumber = so.EstimateId != null ? _context.Estimates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w => w.OrganizationId == organizationId && w.EstimateId == so.EstimateId).SerialNumber : null,
        RecCreateTs = so.RecCreateTs,
        EstimatedDeliveryDate = so.EstimatedDeliveryDate,
        Status = so.Status,
        PriceTotal = so.PriceTotal,
        InRevision = so.InRevision,
        Customer = new Customer { CompanyName = so.Customer.CompanyName },
        CustomerContact = new CustomerContact { FirstName = so.CustomerContact.FirstName, LastName = so.CustomerContact.LastName },
        SalesOrderRevisions = so.InRevision
        ? new List<SalesOrderRevision>
        {
            so.SalesOrderRevisions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Select(soRevision => new SalesOrderRevision
            {
                CustomerContact = new CustomerContact { FirstName = soRevision.CustomerContact.FirstName, LastName = soRevision.CustomerContact.LastName },
                EstimatedDeliveryDate = soRevision.EstimatedDeliveryDate,
                PriceTotal = soRevision.PriceTotal
            }).FirstOrDefault()
        }
        : null
    })
    .ToList();
```

But it didn't work. How can I tell EF Core how to associate each column with the corresponding object property?

Comment: Exactly what version of EF or EF Core are you using?

Comment: I'm using EF Core 3.1

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update to EF Core 7? EF Core 3.1 is still very limited and lacks a lot of functionality (compared to the older non-Core EF 6.4) that only recently was added to EF Core 7.

Comment: What didn't work? Any exception or the result doesn't meet your expectation?

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'No column name was specified for column 4 of 's'.
The column 'FirstName' was specified multiple times for 's'.
Invalid column name 'CustomerId'.
Invalid column name 'CustomerContactId'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raw SQL query has some issues, for example:

```sql
...[CON].FirstName, [CON].LastName, [SOR].FirstName, [SOR].LastName...
```

This results in 2 `FirstName` and 2 `LastName`, and that confuses EF because it won't know which `FirstName` are you mapping into `SalesOrder`.

I'd suggest don't use `.FromSqlRaw(sqlString)` at all, and use proper LINQ to manipulate with the query. We don't know what `SOR` or `CON` or `SO` or `CST` is, so further help might be not possible. But try re-write into LINQ query by yourself first.

Comment: I chose this approach because I used LastIndexOf() in the OrderBy clause and EF couldn't translate that into a SQL query.

Comment: Depends on what the `OrderBy()` is for, you can store the query result in memory first, then do OrderBy locally.

Comment: I need to order by so I can take only 25 sorted records afterwards.
Loading into the memory would mean loading thousands of records.

Comment: Next time please involve those conditions in questions too. For such cases, you can see [if EF provides functions that help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140550/16606026).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the conditions.
EntityFunctions class is available only from .NET 4. I use .NET 3.1

Comment: I'd suggest writing the query into view, then. Along with the columns you need, you can make a column contains `LastIndexOf(...)`, particularly for `OrderBy`. That should make the EF LINQ easier to write.