# Sort IQueryable by specific List value order

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, entity-framework-core, sql-order-by

Is it possible to sort `IQueryable` by indexes of other list, without cast to `IEnumerable`. Entity Framework and Linq can't translate it to SQL query. I also tried `Dictionary<int, Enum>` and function which returns int order.

And I don't want enum values.

Example:

```cs
public enum Letter
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
}

public class MyClass
{
    public Letter LetterEnum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<MyClass> Sort(IQueryable<MyClass> data)
{
    List<Letter> preferredOrder = new List<Letter> { Letter.B, Letter.C, Letter.A };
    return data.OrderBy(x=> preferredOrder.IndexOf(x.LetterEnum)).ThenBy(x=> x.Date);
}
```

Comment: [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211725/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-indexofsystem-string-sys)

Comment: Is it just those three items or is the list dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were a SQL question I would suggest using `case` expression. In linq you could write:

```
return data
           .OrderBy(x => x.LetterEnum == Letter.B ? 1 :
                         x.LetterEnum == Letter.C ? 2 :
                         x.LetterEnum == Letter.A ? 3 : (int?) null)
           .ThenBy(x => x.Date);
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN CAST([t].[LetterEnum] AS int) = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN CAST([t].[LetterEnum] AS int) = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN CAST([t].[LetterEnum] AS int) = 0 THEN 3
    ELSE NULL
END, [t].[Date]
```

Comment: Well, probably better solution than mine, but for dynamic realisation needs a little bit knowledge in Expression Tree generation.

Comment: I did not test what query it generates TBH, but if it creates `case when ...` then I'm OK. Other, better solution (for longer lists) is to join with value-weight pairs.

Comment: It is ok, Join to local collection is not supported by EF.

Answer (score 3):

You can build sorting query dynamically:

```cs
public IQueryable<MyClass> Sort(IQueryable<MyClass> data)
{
    var preferredOrder = new List<Letter> { Letter.B, Letter.C, Letter.A };

    IOrderedQueryable<MyClass>? sorted = null;

    foreach (var orderItem in preferredOrder)
    {
        if (sorted == null)
        {
            sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.LetterEnum == orderItem ? 0 : 1);
        }
        else
        {
            sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.LetterEnum == orderItem ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }

    if (sorted == null)
    {
        sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
    }
    else
    {
        sorted = sorted.ThenBy(x => x.Date);
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Schematically it will generate the following:

```
    return data
        .OrderBy(x => x.LetterEnum == Letter.B ? 0 : 1)
        .ThenBy(x => x.LetterEnum == Letter.C ? 0 : 1)
        .ThenBy(x => x.LetterEnum == Letter.A ? 0 : 1)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic order

Based on the list you specified, they will create a sort

```
public IQueryable<MyClass> Sort(IQueryable<MyClass> data)
{
    List<Letter> preferredOrder = new List<Letter> { Letter.B, Letter.C, Letter.A };

    for (int i = 0; i <= preferredOrder.Count; ++i)
    {
        var value = i == preferredOrder.Count ? 0 : preferredOrder[i];

        if (data is IOrderedQueryable<MyClass> orderedQuery)
        {
            if (i == preferredOrder.Count)
                data = orderedQuery.ThenBy(d => d.Date);
            else
                data = orderedQuery.ThenBy(d => d.LetterEnum == value);
        }
        else
        {
            data = data.OrderBy(d => d.LetterEnum == value);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```