# EF Core: Sort table based on List of int that corresponds with a column in that table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a list:

`List<int> ids = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3 }`

And a table TableA.

I have an `IQueryable<TableA>`, which is not enumerated.

TableA has an column named Id.

I want to order TableA on the column Id based on the order of the values in the list `ids`.

I dont want to do the ordering in memory.

I have tried different approaches, but they have not translated. The closest I got was this:

```cs
var query = from id in ids
                join row in dbQuery
                    on id equals row.Id
                    orderby id descending 
                select row;
```

However, this will only select the union of the id and rows. I want to perform a outer left join, so that I keep the entries in TableA that do not have an Id represented in ids.

I have tried different versions of performing a left join, but they all don't translate. For example:

```
var query = from row in dbQuery
            join id in ids
                on row.Id equals id into rowGroup
            from rowItem in rowGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby rowItem descending
            select row;
```

does not translate in to an SQL query.

Comment: What if a row has the ID that was not on your list? How should you order that row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort IQueryable by specific List value order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424326/sort-iqueryable-by-specific-list-value-order)

Comment: @HunterTran Not sure honestly, preferably at the bottom. But it seems like the accepted answer will allow me to decide that based on requirements.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Maybe, yes! The answer seems similar to the other answer in this post, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create dynamic order
which is the first index of the OrderBy, and others will be ThenBy

Use

```
 var ddd = Sort(context.MenuEntity, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }).ToList();
```

Sort

```
 public IQueryable<MenuEntity> Sort(IQueryable<MenuEntity> query, List<int> ids)
        {
        
            var count = ids.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                int value = ids[i];
                if (query is IOrderedQueryable<MenuEntity> orderedQuery)
                {
                    query = orderedQuery.ThenBy(d => d.Id == value);
                }
                else
                {
                    query = query.OrderBy(d => d.Id == value);
                }
            }
            return query;
        }
```

I qet Query in Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[MenuId], [m].[ParentId], [m].[Title]
FROM [MenuEntity] AS [m]
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN [m].[Id] = @__value_0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, CASE
    WHEN [m].[Id] = @__value_1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, CASE
    WHEN [m].[Id] = @__value_2 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END',N'@__value_0 int,@__value_1 int,@__value_2 int',@__value_0=1,@__value_1=2,@__value_2=3
```

Sort  Descending

```
  public IQueryable<MenuEntity> Sort(IQueryable<MenuEntity> query, List<int> ids)
        {

            var count = ids.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                int value = ids[i];
                if (query is IOrderedQueryable<MenuEntity> orderedQuery)
                {
                    query = orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(d => d.Id == value);
                }
                else
                {
                    query = query.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id == value);
                }
            }
            return query;
        }
```

Comment: This works, but in my case the List of ids are already sorted, so I want to order my query by the order of those Id's, and then I need to use your second method with `ThenByDescending` and `OrderByDescending` to keep the order correctly. Thank you!