# foreach vs LINQ to find difference between collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ArrayList ids` containing `String` objects that are IDs, and another `ArrayList objs` containing objects which have a string ID field.  Right now I have code, to find which `ids` don't have a match in `objs`, which looks like this:

```
var missing = new List<string>();

foreach (MyObj obj in objs)
{
    if (!ids.Contains(obj.ID))
    {
       missing.Add(obj.ID);
    }
}
```

This works fine.  But I rewrote it to this an exercise to better "think in LINQ":

```
var missing = objs.Cast<MyObj>().Select(x => x.ID).Except(ids.Cast<string>());
```

[I expected this LINQ to be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/linq-statement-faster-than-foreach-loop/7807839) than the `foreach` + `Contains` approach (especially due to the `Cast` calls), but the LINQ runs significantly faster.  What is the LINQ approach doing differently that gives the performance benefit?

Comment: The linq approach is not executed, that's why it's faster. `Except` is using deferred execution. Apart from that it's using a set which is efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter what do you mean by this?

Comment: Include a `missing.ToList()` and measure again.

Comment: `missing` is a query not a collection. Use   `foreach` or `ToList` to execute the query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter deferred by IEnumerable<string> instead of making a List<string>.  Thanks, making sense now.

Comment: @jltrem: A `List<string>` is also an `IEnumerable<string>`. Here are some informations about deferred execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq

Comment: @HenkHolterman now that `missing` is _doing_ something it takes some time.  Still significantly faster than my `foreach` + `Contains` processing.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ `Except` uses `HashSet` internally, which has *O(1)* `Contains` method performance, when it's *O(n)* for `ArrayList`. That's why it's faster.

But as *Tim* pointed in his comment, your `Except` approach does not really produce any results. It just defines a query. The query is executed as soon as you need results. And it may be executed more than once. You should add `ToList()` call to get `List<T>` explicitly:

```
var missing = objs.Cast<MyObj>().Select(x => x.ID).Except(ids.Cast<string>()).ToList();
```

By the way, why are you using `ArrayList` instead of generic `List<T>`?

Comment: The `ArrayList` is provided somewhere else in the system that I'm working in.  Not something I have control over right now.

Answer (score 1):

[`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) uses a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) (or something similar) to efficiently find what object are the same, while your code uses the less-efficient `List<T>.Contains` (or similar) method.