# Min() and Max() or single oldschool foreach?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

If I have big collection and I care about performance, should I believe in miracle and use

```
var min = Y.Min();
var max = Y.Max();
```

or I better be a good engineer and use

```
var max = double.NegativeInfinity;
var min = double.PositiveInfinity;
foreach(var y in Y)
{
    if(y > max)
        max = y;
    if(y < min)
        min = y;
}
```

`Y` is `ICollection<double>`, because I need `Count` and `foreach`. I am curious if type is right, because of min/max and that I will need to iterate collection from end, so there will be

```
Y.OrderByDescending((o) => o)...
```

Comment: Why not try them both and measure them?  Is the performance difference significant enough to use less-intuitive code?

Comment: You could init `min` & `max` with the first element of collection, and use `else if (y < min)`.

Comment: Your final question is very confusing - why do you need to call `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @DStanley, my knowledge are not solid. I've heard something about *magic* of linq, where it can optimize queries or *delay* something (processing?). I am looking for a solution, where `Min`, `Max` and `OrderByDescending` would outperform blunt `foreach` (if that possible ofc). Or simple confirmation, what `foreach` is the best.

Comment: Calling `Min` and `Max` is `O(n)` + `O(n)` = `O(2n)` whereas a loop is simply `O(n)`. Now ask yourself which is efficient ?

Comment: obviously single foreach loop will be faster.

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed the OP wanted to use `First` and `Last` to find the max and min (which still iterates twice)

Comment: @DStanley: But ordering it will be O(n log n), so that's more expensive than just calling Min and Max.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ordering has nothing to do with min and max. I simply need to iterate from the end at some point. `Y` is coordinate, later point will have priority in hit test. In hit test I will iterate backward. I provide that info in addition to original question for a possible *tip* (see my question about type).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, so, no miracle?

Comment: So you need the results in an ordered form *separately* to needing the min and max? That's really *really* not clear from the question.

Comment: @Sinatr: if you're going to need to order your list anyways, why do you need to do an extra for-loop? The `First()` should be the max and the `Last()` should be the min, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I would use older then oldschool for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "magic" to Linq that will optimize queries like that.  All it does is add iterators on top of the collections.  Linq is designed to improve *coding efficiency*, not raw performance.

There *may be* cases where a Linq query will perform faster than a `foreach`, but this isn't one of them.  `Min` and `Max` are two separate operations, so the compiler would have to "look ahead" to see what operations are being done to know whether they could be combined into a single iteration.  It's not that sophisticated.

Comment: Pretty straightforward and my doubts have gone.. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Y` is `IEnumerable<double>` then calling `Y.Max()` for example will call the following overload of `System.Linq.Enumerable.Max()` (comments my own, source decompiled from `System.Core.dll`):

```
public static double Max(this IEnumerable<double> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    double num = 0.0; // current max
    bool flag = false; // is first iteration
    foreach (double num2 in source)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            if (num2 > num || double.IsNaN(num))
            {
                num = num2;
            }
        }
        else // initialization case
        {
            num = num2;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag) // throw if there were no elements
    {
        return num;
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

As a general rule of thumb, if something already exists to do what you want - use that - unless you observe any performance issues then you may need to optimise.

Comment: Thanks. What if it's not `IEnumerable`? Is there *better type* for what I need?

Comment: @Sinatr If it's not `IEnumerable` then you can't use `foreach` anyway!

Comment: Well, maybe I shouldn't? Like I mention, it's `ICollection` atm, so that I can have `Count` **property** (not sure if I must, maybe linq `Count()` method for `IEnumerable` is same fast, but I suspect it's `O(n)` to count everything). Perhaps there is other, better type, what allow me to iterate collection somehow (to example, by using `ToEnumerable()`, assuming what such call will be less expensive than min, max and reverseordering)?

Comment: I think you need to read up on interfaces. `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. A neat trick is to hit `F12` on things (assuming you're using Visual Studio) - this will show you the definition and allow you to see what interfaces it implements.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, never thought of going to definition of *not-mine* code for a quick info. In any case, I know what `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable` indirectly (because, well, my code is working in `foreach`), my question was if it should be `ISomeSuperType` instead to have `O(n)` for min/max calculation (to be able to use linq and have nice looking code). And don't forget `OrderByDescending`, I already don't feel good with `ICollection`, because it can't iterate reverse (like `List` or `Array` by using index).

Comment: @Sinatr I think you're overthinking this right now.  You're focusing on micro-optimizing a query that may not even be a problem in the final program!  You might have other elements (UI, data access) that far outweigh the query in terms of processing time.  Use the tools that makes you the most efficient, profile your program, and optimize the slowest parts first.

Comment: +1M to what @DStanley said. You've probably spent many orders of magnitude more time worrying about these few lines of code than the amount of total execution time they'll ever see.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a SortedList with the Key and Value being the same:

```
var list = new SortedList<double, double> { { 4, 4}, { 9, 9}, { 7, 7} };
var min = list.Keys[0];
var max = list.Keys[list.Count - 1];
```

First value will always be the min, last the max. Doesn't help much with the order by as it is ascending. Also, its not very efficient to insert into so if you care about performance of creating it (as opposed to reading from it) it isn't such a great choice.

Comment: Great idea. This is what I call *some other type* indeed. In my case any change in `Y` (`list` in your code) will require recalculating of min, max and hit test (not sure yet), which may be way more expensive, than having `SortedList` from start. New items will be only added. However, I will start removing first item at some point, so still not pretty happy about it.