# string.contains item from combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, search, combobox

Another complex one, I have searched everywhere and have only been able to find answers to 'how do i find a string in a combo box'

I want to know the opposite. I have a combo box filled with cities (strings) and I am passed an address string.

I would like to search my address string to see if it contains any one of the cities currently in my combo box.

eg. Combo box contains: London, Paris, Berlin

Addresses passed in:

- 123, street, town, London, Postcode (True)
- 123, street, town, Rome,
  Postcode (False)

I was thinking along the lines of

```
address.Contains(combobox.Any().ToString());
```

but as you can probably tell, that doesnt work!

Comment: You need to check non over combobox, but the over *content* it shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `ComboBox` contains all string items then you can use `Enumerable.OfType<string>` and then apply LINQ operator `Any` like:

```
bool ifExist = combobox.Items.OfType<string>()
                         .Any(cbItem => address.Contains(cbItem);
```

For case insensitive comparison do:

```
bool ifExist = combobox.Items.OfType<string>()
             .Any(cbItem => address.IndexOf(cbItem, 
                                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
                                            > -1);
```

Comment: This compiles, give me a second to test, could be the winner!

Comment: Much better example than what was previously suggested in regards to doing a for-loop this is much more efficient in my opinion +1

Comment: Fantastic, fixed the issue perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MethodMan: why should it be more efficient? Doesn't it result in the same internal operations? There must be code to cycle over all items of the combobox, searching for given data. Based on what I found, its better readable, but much slower: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/linq-statement-faster-than-foreach-loop

Comment: @TobiasKnauss, I agree with you partially. If there is going to be any performance difference it would be negligible. It is no more efficient than a for/foreach loop, but it more readable and easier to maintain. But it will not be *much* slower.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I agree partially as well however I am not going to debate style / preference your opinion has been noted...

Comment: `OrdinalIgnoreCase` would be a better choice for all cultures. `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` may not be a good way in some of them.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to search my address string to see if it contains any one of the cities currently in my combo box.

```
bool addressContainsCity = combobox.Items.OfType<string>.Any(item => address.Contains(item));
```

OR

```
bool addressContainsCity = combobox.Items.Cast<string>.Any(item => address.Contains(item));
```

Comment: I haven't voted it yet! Don't understand the downvote either! This looks like a great answer, I have tried implementing it but it's not allowing me to use combobox.items.any. (system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection does not contain a definitiion for any)
Could this be because i'm using .net 4? and any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess `Enumerable.Any` can't be applied with `Items` property. It doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @chutzzz, your current code in the answer doesn't compile. Modify your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't like LINQ:

make a for-loop over all combobox items, and call the `address.Contains()` on all string values of the combobox items.

Comment: and I don't ;-) Also, it seems to be slower, see my comment on your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well there could be a couple ways you could do this. This is the way I would approach it:

```
string[] arg = address.Split(',');
combobox.Items.Contains(arg[3]);
```

This should work if I understand what you are trying to do, and the City is always in the same position in the string.

Comment: why would the OP need to use the `Split()` function when linq / lambda can be used quickly to determine it something is contained

Comment: I never said this is the only way to do it. I said this is the way I would do it. Only because I am more comfortable with the `Split()` function than I am with lambdas.