# Linq - How To Check Intersecting Objects Between Lists

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two list of objects. For e.g. say the objects are like below

```
class A
{
    int ID;
    int Value;
}

class B
{
    int ID;
    int Value;
}
```

I have two list of above objects like `List<A> AList` and `List<B> BList`. I want to find if any object in `List<B>` has matching Value from `List<A>`.

For now, what I do like is

```
foreach(var item in AList)
{
    if(!BList.Any(x => x.Value == item.Value))
    {
        //Handle the error message
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do it by Linq?

Comment: Use contain . objListB.contains(objListA);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. This will be true if there are any items in BList that have matching values in AList:

```
BList.Any(b => AList.Select(a => a.Value).Contains(b.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
from a in AList
join b in BList on a.Value equals b.Value
select a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BList.Any(b => AList.Any(a => a.Value == b.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've tried and it seems to work just fine:

```
    class First
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Second
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var firstList = new List<First>
            {
                new First { Id = 1, Value = 2 },
                new First { Id = 1, Value = 10 },
                new First { Id = 1, Value = 0 }
            };

            var secondList = new List<Second>
            {
                new Second { Id = 1, Value = 2 },
                new Second { Id = 1, Value = 2 },
                new Second { Id = 1, Value = 4 }
            };

            bool hasCommonValues = firstList.Select(f => f)
                                   .Any(u => secondList.Select(x => x.Value)
                                   .Contains(u.Value));

            Console.WriteLine(hasCommonValues);        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your current code, and if you just need to handle error when *any item* in `AList` doesn't have a matching item in `BList`, you can do as follows :

```
if (AList.Any(a => !BList.Any(b => b.Value == a.Value)))
{
    //Handle error
}
```

Or if you need to take an action on *every item* in `AList` that doesn't have a matching item in `BList` :

```
foreach(var item in AList.Where(a => !BList.Any(b => b.Value == a.Value)))
{
    //Handle error for current `item`
}
```

Anyways, the reason to prefer LINQ over conventional `foreach` loop is usually more for its readability (shorter, cleaner, easier to maintain, etc.) rather than performance. For reference : [Is a LINQ statement faster than a 'foreach' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop)