# What is the most efficient method to calculate total numbers in a DataTable Column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with a Column of numbers called `x value`

I want to return the sum value that column.

The column will always have a number in it (so no need to worry about blank / null values).

My code:

```
            int x = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in SqlCon.ds.Tables[3].Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in  SqlCon.ds.Tables[3].Columns)
                {
                    if (dc.ColumnName == "x value")
                    {
                        //calc value
                    }

                }
            }
```

Many Thanks,

ps. have looked on SO already but cannot find the duplicate (I assume it is about but it's Monday morning and my google skill aren't the best!)

Comment: What do you mean by *best* ? fastest ?

Comment: @user3185569 most efficient sorry. Will update question.

Comment: The most concise: `int sum = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => (int)row["x"]);`

Comment: `var sum = dataTable.Compute("SUM(xvalue)")`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov submit as answerand ill mark it as correct as this has resolved my issue. Not that educated on Linq but seems to of worked!

Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop foreach is more efficient than linq, although less readable.

Comment: If you are really interested in performance (*most efficient* is just as unclear as *best*), since you have a `SqlCon` you should probably ditch the DataTable alltogether and go for native SQL. It will surely be faster than anything with DataTable.

Comment: Impressive if the "Community" bot now can close duplicates successfully (as in "closing them correct"). Have never seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop over each row, that's for sure. However, you can get the column index once to avoid unnecessary looping for the columns:

```
int sum = 0;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[3];
int columnIndex = dt.Columns["x column"].Ordinal;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dr[columnIndex]);
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using that over: `int sum = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => (int)row["x"]);` 

Thanks

Comment: @SCramphorn foreach is faster than linq (Since you're is targeting effeciency): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @SCramphorn and it is for sure faster than `.Compute()` try them out and compare on large data.

Comment: Many Thanks. I will try

Comment: Just tried and makes a lot more sense when I stepped through it. So in the end it was the Convert.ToInt32 I needed, but in terms of performance i understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
object sumOfX = SqlCon.ds.Tables[3].Compute("Sum(x value)", null);
```

Then cast to appropriate number type.

See [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note: this might be *efficient* in terms of writing code, but there are probably more efficient approaches in terms of performance if you really need to squeeze the last clock cycle... but then again, using DataTable and C# might be the wrong choice.