# Filter c# list using timestamp, Take first record of each 5 seconds

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a scenario like to filter the record based on timings.That is first record in a range of 5 seconds.

Example :

Input data :

```
data timings 
1452 10:00:11
1455 10:00:11
1252 10:00:13
1952 10:00:15
1454 10:00:17
1451 10:00:19
1425 10:00:20
1425 10:00:21
1459 10:00:23
1422 10:00:24
```

Expected output

```
1452 10:00:11
1454 10:00:17
1459 10:00:23
```

I have tried to group the data based on timings like below

```
 listSpacialRecords=listSpacialRecords.GroupBy(x => x.timings).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

But using this i can only filter the data using same time.
It hope someone can  help me to resolve this 
List contain huge data, so is there any way rather than looping through list ?

Comment: Is the input allways in order?

Comment: @CSharpie yes it will be in order

Comment: Is the data stored in a database, meaning that your `.GroupBy` and similar is actually LINQ to SQL or to Entities? Or is this in-memory processing? You comment on an answer here that `foreach` will be a headache, can you explain why that is?

Comment: Also, when you say *each 5 seconds*, do you mean "after row X, pick the next row that comes at least 5 seconds after X", or do you mean "for each of the second intervals 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, etc. take the first row? The meaning is different. In the first, a row with 13 would not be followed by a row of 16, but in the second it would.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen data is not there in database. We are migrating data from a local folder to server based on conditions.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  pick the next row that comes at least 5 seconds after X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var results =
    source
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            source.Take(1).ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (x.timings.Subtract(a.Last().timings).TotalSeconds >= 5.0)
                {
                    a.Add(x);
                }
                return a;
            });
```

I get your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This should do (assuming listSpacialRecords is in order)

```
var result = new List<DateTime>();
var distance = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); 
var pivot = default(DateTime);
foreach(var record in listSpacialRecords)
{    
    if(record.timings > pivot)
    {
       result.Add(record.timings); // yield return record.timings; as an alternative if you need defered execution
       pivot = record.timings +distance;
    }
}
```

If not, easiest but maybe not the most efficient way would be to change the foreach a littlebit

```
foreach(var time in listSpacialRecords.OrderBy(t=>t))
```

Doing this only using Linq is possible, but wont benefit readability.

Comment: List contain huge data , so foreach will be a headake

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV there is no way around a foreach.
I modified to make it more efficient for many records.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately me timings property is a datetime and pivot is Timespan so it is giving error . property is timespan then  answer is perfect  +1  for that

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV fixed.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your class looks something like this:

```
public class DataNode
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Timings { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataNode> TimeFilter(this IEnumerable<DataNode> list, int timeDifference )
    {
        DataNode LastFound = null;
        foreach (var item in list.OrderByDescending(p=> p.Timings))
        {
            if (item.Timings > LastFound?.Timings.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,timeDifference)))
            {
                LastFound = item;
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

This can then be used like this

```
        var list = new List<DataNode>();

        var result  = list.TimeFilter(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this approach may work, using the [% Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) (Modulo)

**Assumptions**

- The list is in order
- You don't care if it skips missing seconds
- There is always a first element
- And this is only within a 24 hour period

*Note : Totally untested*

```
    var seconds = listSpacialRecords
                     .First()         // get the first element
                     .Timmings
                     .TimeOfDay       // convert it to TimeSpan
                     .TotalSeconds;   // get the total seconds of the day    

    var result = listSpacialRecords
                      .Where(x => (x.Timmings
                                   .TimeOfDay
                                   .TotalSeconds - seconds) % 5 == 0) 
                                    // get the difference and mod 5
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: what is -seconds ??

Comment: Ahh ok its the baseline so it starts at 0 and the first record is included in the results, well that was the idea, i have added brackets

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Timmings or Timings ?

Comment: The modulo operator (or whatever you call that) is not going to produce the expected outcome. In the given data in the question your query would return 11, 15, 20, not 11, 17, 23. It's apparently not about the 5 second intervals but 5 seconds apart.

Comment: output is different