# Clean duplicates and their instances from a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a datamodel like this :

```
    public class AmpFile
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string actualpath { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have a list of it like this :

```
[ list member 1 ]    -    filename:  "testfile1.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "C:\testpath\testfile1.jpg" 
[ list member 2 ]    -    filename:  "brickwall.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg" 
[ list member 3 ]    -    filename:  "mydata.txt"    -    actualpath:  "D:\mydata.txt" 
[ list member 4 ]    -    filename:  "testfile1.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "E:\demo\testfile1.jpg" 
[ list member 5 ]    -    filename:  "mydata.txt"    -    actualpath:  "F:\somefolder\mydata.txt" 
[ list member 6 ]    -    filename:  "testfile1.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "F:\somefolder\testfile1.jpg" 
[ list member 7 ]    -    filename:  "testfile2.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "F:\somefolder\testfile2.jpg" 
[ list member 7 ]    -    filename:  "testfile3.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "D:\testfile3.jpg"
```

Now I want to find duplicates of each member and if there's a duplicate of it , I want to remove duplicates + the reference itself so the result I want to achieve is :

```
[ list member 1 ]    -    filename:  "brickwall.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg" 
[ list member 2 ]    -    filename:  "testfile2.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "F:\somefolder\testfile2.jpg" 
[ list member 3 ]    -    filename:  "testfile3.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "D:\testfile3.jpg"
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can you be more clear please, what did you call a "duplicate" (same filename ? same path ? Both ?) ? What did you want to delete (only the duplicates ? the duplicates AND the original ?) ?

Comment: @kiliz yes exactly I want to find duplicate filenames like testfile1.jpg without caring the addresses and delete the duplicates and original reference (first found on the list ...)

Comment: Please don't post data like `[ list member 1 ]    -    filename:  "testfile1.jpg"    -    actualpath:  "C:\testpath\testfile1.jpg"` when valid C# would allow us to write and test code for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with Linq, by using [**Group by**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) and filter all elements that have `count == 1`, like the following code:
1 - Prepare list of `ampFile`:

```
List<AmpFile> ampFiles = new List<AmpFile>
{
    new AmpFile{filename="testfile1.jpg",actualpath="C:\\testpath\\testfile1.jpg"},
    new AmpFile{filename="brickwall.jpg",actualpath="C:\\testpath\\brickwall.jpg"},
    new AmpFile{filename="mydata.txt",actualpath="D:\\mydata.txt"},
    new AmpFile{filename="testfile1.jpg",actualpath="E:\\demo\testfile1.jpg"},
    new AmpFile{filename="mydata.txt",actualpath="F:\\somefolder\\mydata.txt"},
    new AmpFile{filename="testfile1.jpg",actualpath="F:\\somefolder\\testfile1.jpg"},
    new AmpFile{filename="testfile2.jpg",actualpath="F:\\somefolder\\testfile2.jpg"},
    new AmpFile{filename="testfile3.jpg",actualpath="D:\\testfile3.jpg"},
};
```

2 - Call `groupBy` and filter with `Where`:

```
List<AmpFile> notDuplicatedAmpFiles = ampFiles.GroupBy(x => x.filename)
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

3 - Demo:

```
foreach(AmpFile ampFile in notDuplicatedAmpFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"fileName :{ampFile.filename}, actualPath :{ampFile.actualpath}");
}
```

4 - Result:

```
fileName :brickwall.jpg, actualPath :C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg
fileName :testfile2.jpg, actualPath :F:\somefolder\testfile2.jpg
fileName :testfile3.jpg, actualPath :D:\testfile3.jpg
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I'd suggest `.Skip(1).Any() == false` over `x.Count() == 1` as the first only iterates the first two elements of a group, but the latter has to iterate the entire group.

Comment: @RoadRunner - On an `ICollection<T>` it is, but not on a pure `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @RoadRunner - But in this case a grouping is a `ICollection<>T>` (it's a `internal class Grouping : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>, IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable, IList<TElement>, ICollection<TElement>`). Time to move on. Nothing to see here.

Comment: thank you for this great answer , I accepted your answer because it was the best , Can you tell me how can I reverse this thing and get removed members as a separated list too ?

Comment: @DraculaBytePair you're welcome, change just the filter like ``Where(x => x.Count() >1)`` or use [**Except**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) with a custom comparer.

Comment: @Sajid I used `.Where(x => x.Count() != 1)` and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this query:

```
var results =
    from a in list
    group a by a.filename into gas
    where !gas.Skip(1).Any()
    from ga in gas.Take(1)
    select ga;
```

If you start with this data:

```
var list = new List<AmpFile>()
{
    new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"C:\testpath\testfile1.jpg" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "brickwall.jpg", actualpath = @"C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "mydata.txt", actualpath = @"D:\mydata.txt" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"E:\demo\testfile1.jpg" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "mydata.txt", actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\mydata.txt" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\testfile1.jpg" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile2.jpg", actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\testfile2.jpg" },
    new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile3.jpg", actualpath = @"D:\testfile3.jpg" },
};
```

...then you get this result:

[image: results]

Comment: very well solution and I didn't know I can use SQL like commands with linq , thanks for teaching me this. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEquals like code below.  Your paths are in different folders so you do not have any duplicates.  See below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<AmpFile> files = new List<AmpFile>() {
                new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"C:\testpath\testfile1.jpg"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "brickwall.jpg", actualpath = @"C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "mydata.txt", actualpath = @"D:\mydata.txt"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"E:\demo\testfile1.jpg"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "mydata.txt", actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\mydata.txt"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile1.jpg" , actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\testfile1.jpg"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile2.jpg" , actualpath = @"F:\somefolder\testfile2.jpg"}, 
                new AmpFile() { filename = "testfile3.jpg", actualpath = @"D:\testfile3.jpg"}
            };

            List<AmpFile> output = files.Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
    public class AmpFile : IEquatable<AmpFile>
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string actualpath { get; set; }

        public Boolean Equals(AmpFile other)
        {
            return ((this.filename == other.filename) && (this.actualpath == other.actualpath));
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (this.filename + "^" + this.actualpath).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about getting a new list instead of deleting from the original list, you can do like this (sorry for complexity, I think it can be easly optimized → adding breaks ect...) :

```
List<AmpFile> foo(List<AmpFile> files)
{
 List<AmpFile> result = new List<AmpFile>();
 bool add = false;
 foreach(AmpFile file in files)
 {
  add = true;
  foreach(AmpFile alreadyAdded in result)
  {
   if(file.filename == alreadyAdded.filename)
   {
    add = false;
   }
  }
  if(add)
  {
   result.Add(file);
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

If you really need to change the original list, you can do something like this (can again be optimized) :

```
void foo2(List<AmpFile> files)
{
 AmpFile[] temp = files.ToArray();
 List<AmpFile> toDelete = new List<AmpFile>();
 foreach(AmpFile file in temp)
 {
  foreach(AmpFile f in files)
  {
   if(f != file && f.filename == file.filename)
   {
    if(!toDelete.Contains(f))
    {
     toDelete.Add(f);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 foreach(AmpFile file in toDelete)
 {
   files.Remove(file);
 }
}
```

Comment: You can do it a lot faster using the numerical indexer instead of the enumerator.

Comment: I've been using too many IEnuerators lately, so I'm a little bit formatted, sorry ! ^^'7

Comment: @jscarle why did you say that numerical indexer is faster than enumerator ? I'm busy in speed optimisation stuff curently and I'm interested to this info, I haven't seen this anywhere, have you any reference source that I can read explaining it ?

Comment: What language is this? The OP is using C#.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's C#, why ? I've made a mistake ?

Comment: `foreach(Ampfile f : files)`. You should test everything that you can before posting.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here for an in-depth discussion on for vs foreach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach

Comment: exact, I've to use "in" in C#, sorry, i'm coding in a different language while answering, I'm correcting ^^'7

Comment: mistake fixed !

Comment: thanks @jscarle really usefull, I'm gonna have something to read tonight ^^

Comment: Now, to be fussy, the OP's type was `AmpFile`, but you've used `Ampfile`.

Comment: Also, this code doesn't work. It's keeping one of the items in a duplicate. The OP wants all items removed if they belong to a duplicate.

Comment: `foo2` also doesn't compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213000/discussion-between-kiliz-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score -1):

Running two loops on your list is the fastest way.

```
List<AmpFile> ampList = new List<AmpFile>();
// Populate list

for (int i = 0; i < ampList.Count; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ampList.Count; j++)
        if (ampList[j].filename == ampList[i].filename)
            ampList.RemoveAt(j);
```

Comment: 1) You will get some warnings because you're modifying a List while enumerating on it. 2) `.Length` doesn't exists for Lists, use `.Count`. But the general idea is good

Comment: Good catch for the Count, I'm writing this from memory. You won't get a warning because using the indexer isn't enumerating. You are enumerating the list when you call the enumerator, ei: foreach.

Comment: This code doesn't work. It's keeping one of the items in a duplicate. The OP wants all items removed if they belong to a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class AmpFile
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string actualpath { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<AmpFile> lstemail = new List<AmpFile>();
        lstemail.Add(new AmpFile { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath= "C:\testpath\testfile1.jpg"});
        lstemail.Add(new AmpFile { filename = "brickwall.jpg", actualpath = "C:\testpath\brickwall.jpg" });
        lstemail.Add(new AmpFile { filename = "mydata.txt", actualpath = @"D:\mydata.txt" });
        lstemail.Add(new AmpFile { filename = "testfile1.jpg", actualpath = @"E:\demo\testfile1.jpg" });

        var myDistinctList = lstemail.GroupBy(i => 
   i.filename).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
     lstemail = myDistinctList;

    }
}
}
```

I have used linq better to use over than foreach.

Comment: "I have used linq it is faster than foreach." - faster in what way?

Comment: LINQ is by far the slowest approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop

Comment: I mean LINQ is better to use over a foreach loop, because it gives you much cleaner and easy-to-understand code. But LINQ is slower than foreach