# Optimize or Transform the below for loop on an observable collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Below is my query- when a new element comes to the `StoriesCollection` `RangeObservableCollection`.
I'm moving the elements in the collection based on below logic:
(pinned entries should be fixed in the grid so I am checking if the new entry is pinned/unpinned, if it is unpinned then I am moving the other elements in the collection by one place each to fit the new element).
please help to optimize it with LINQ.

```
private void AdjustPinnedStories()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < StoriesCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            if (StoriesCollection[i].IsPinned)
            {
                if (!StoriesCollection[i - 1].IsPinned)
                {
                    StoriesCollection.Move(i, i - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: LINQ is about convenience and not about efficiency. Its like asking to help win an F1 race with a luxury motor home.

Comment: Also, LINQ is for querying, and generally shouldn't be used for mutational purposes (i.e. your `Move` method), although you could hack a solution using `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not going to make your code more optimized, at least not in the sense of faster. It introduces some overhead and still has to go through the for loop, so in facts it’s going to be (marginally) slower.

The advantage of LINQ is faster And shorter code writing. If your loop already does what you want, you are better with leaving it as is.

Check [this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156059/is-a-linq-statement-faster-than-a-foreach-loop)