# Comparing each column value in DataRow without using for/each loop

Tags: c#

Is there a way to achieve the same below output without using for/each loop? (using  lambda expression?)

```
DataRow leftDataRow = GetReferenceDataRow();
DataTable table = GetTableForComparison():
List<NonMatchingValue> listColumnsWithDiscrepancies = new List<NonMatchingValue>();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < table.Columns.Count; index++)
    {
        if (leftDataRow[index].ToString() != row[index].ToString())
        {
            listColumnsWithDiscrepancies.Add(new  NonMatchingValue {
                FieldSource = leftDataRow.Tables.Columns[index].ColumnName,
                FieldTarget = row.Table.Columns[index].ColumnName
                ValueSource = leftDataRow[index].ToString(),
                ValueTarget = row[index].ToString(),
                IsEqual = leftDataRow[index].Equal(row[index])
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The structure/number of columns of leftDataRow and rows in the table is identical.

// Sample Output:

```
FieldSource |   FieldTarget |   ValueSource |   ValueTarget |   IsEqual
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Column1     |   Column1     |   X           |   Y           |   False
Column2     |   Column2     |   A           |   A           |   True
```

Comment: Can you do a SQL query to fetch the rows?  If yes, write the query as "where (col1 <> ?) or (col2 <> ?) or (col3 <> ?) ..." and supply the reference row values for the "?".  With that, the database engine does the inner loop for you.

Comment: @DaveS, not fetching data from  database

Comment: How many **columns** are present in the table (and reference row) ?

Comment: @Steve - rows from table and reference row are identical in structure.

Comment: My idea is to search for the identical rows using the DataTable.Select method and then remove these identical rows from the table. The remaining rows are the different ones. Probably a loop will be still required but with a lot less of cycles.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a "for/each loop" ?

Comment: Did you (try to) use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq)  ?

Comment: @Luuk - I'm not familiar with LINQ

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262860/724039, But also do read the other answers in that question, and give it a try.