# Merging listviewcollections

Tags: c#, listview, .net-3.5

Let's say I have two listviews, called A & B. I fill A with 20 items, and a few minutes later, I also fill B with 20 items. Both lists contain completely different data with no duplicates.

Now, for some reason unbeknownst to us, I get in the crazy mood to add the contents in B to listview A. Of course I can do this using a simple `ForEach` loop, where I go over every item in B and add it to A.

But this takes time and processing power! Really old systems (think about crappy CE handhelds) will surely beg for mercy! So I got to thinking, what if there was a way to merge the listviewcollection of B with the listviewcollection of A in one go?

**Is it possible to merge two listviewcollections without a `ForEach` loop?**

Comment: What version of .net are you using? How many items are those two lists containing? Does some items in B are already in A and need to be filtered out to avoid duplicates?

Comment: I've updated the question a bit to provide the information requested in your questions.

Comment: You might not gain any performance, because even using the `AddRange` method can be quite slow.  At some level, someone has to add to the collection.  I have found that it's often better to do it by hand...get both collections into a friendly format, merge, then clear the original collection and add back your newly merged one.  As @allo_man has suggested, there might be other things you want to do, and this way you have total control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
MyLvCollection.Items.AddRange( 
MyOtherLvCollection.Select(wi => new ListViewDataItem( 
    wi.Name, new string[]{wi.ID.ToString()} ) ).ToArray() );
```

EDIT: If you really want it performed client-side (not a web service etc)... then look into using a [CompositeCollection](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/using-composite-collection-in-c/), don't know it's performance but seems like the solution for your dilemma using something like XAML.

Comment: I would be using a syntax like this one, but linq isn't faster than foreach and for 20 items I don't see how a device even a very old CE device would be run to the ground. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044236/nested-foreach-vs-lambda-linq-query-performancelinq-to-objects

Comment: Are you running a webserver on a CE device? If not why in this context would server side code be affected by the client?

Comment: P.S. Have you looked into using a CompositeCollection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx