# Slow foreach() for Column update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, csla

I want to update a column of a table which got ~4k rows. The column has to get the date of the parent so I'm using a simple foreach:

```
Parent.VariableDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var item in Parent.ChildList)
{
    item.vari = Parent.VariableDate ;

}
```

**Problem:**

This action is taking ages. Can I immediately update a whole column?

Comment: Don't know `WPF`, but does it has `BeginUpdate` or `SuspendLayout` analog? Try to avoid refreshing your changes somehow, possibly by creating the whole list of items unbound and then adding it to a control at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll gain very much from writing this any other way. A better option, if possible in your situation(?), might be to avoid using `VariableDate` at all in each item in `ChildList`, and just refer to `Parent` instead whenever you need it. That way, you would not have to iterate through the 4K rows at all.

As presented in your question, each `item.VariableDate` seems to be superfluous..

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq for that

```
Parent.ChildList.foreach(p=>p.vari = DateTime.Now);
```

it is the fastest way

Comment: Are you sure this will provide any better than a simple ForEach()? Seems to me the only difference here is some minor syntax changes..

Comment: in fact, linq is not necessary faster. It executes deferred and can be faster than a "coded" solution. But to say "it is the fastest way" is way too absolute and plain wrong. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044236/nested-foreach-vs-lambda-linq-query-performancelinq-to-objects for example.

Comment: @techloverr Have _you_ tried?  :p I'm just asking for some justification for your claim.